# Fullcalendar Google: Filter by location

Tags: fullcalendar

Within Fullcalendar I'm trying to filter out specific events using the location strings coming from google calendar. e.g. only show events with location string of "Room 1"

```
$('#calendar') .fullCalendar( {

        googleCalendarApiKey: 'MYAPIKEY',
        defaultView: 'listDay',

        events: {
            googleCalendarId: 'CALENDARID',
            }


            });
```

I have looked through the docs and have tried `removeEvents`and `clientEvents` but not sure how you specify to the library to pick up on Google API's location strings.

EDIT:
Adapted this from another post from the stack. It does give a type error so probably messed up the code `"indexOf($('Room 2').val()) >= 0}"`, I've tried combinations of this but no luck. I think this is the right code though, just not implementing it correctly.

```
    $('#calendar') .fullCalendar( {

    googleCalendarApiKey: 'MYAPIKEY',
    defaultView: 'listDay',

    events: {
        googleCalendarId: 'CALENDARID',
        }

    eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) {
                 return ['all', event.location].indexOf($('Room 2').val()) >= 0}
```